# Browser Preload Scanning and Javascript File Placement

Tags: javascript, html

I spent a few hours over the last few days reworking some of my javascript files so they could all be loaded toward the end of my source code (or, if they must be placed earlier, they would wait for jQuery to be defined, which is loaded in the footer but is required by most of my scripts). I then moved all scripts that could be moved to end of the source code.

So a rough example of the change..

Original:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is still an awesome web page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.example.com/path/to/another/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jQuery/or/some/other/important/library.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>lots of great content</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/this/script/must/be/located/in/the/body.js"></script>
    <p>more great content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Updated:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is an awesome web page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>lots of great content and maybe lots of images too</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/this/script/must/be/located/in/the/body.js"></script>
    <p>more great content</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.example.com/path/to/another/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jQuery/or/some/other/important/library.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I made that change and looked at Chrome's Network traffic when I reloaded some pages. I was surprised to discover that Chrome still loads my javascripts before loading images and such.

I did some reading and it seems like this is due to Chrome's preloader (https://plus.google.com/+IlyaGrigorik/posts/8AwRUE7wqAE) scanning ahead and loading important files sooner.

If Chrome (and other modern browsers I assume) are going to do this, then is there any reason to continue placing javascripts toward the end of the source code?

Comment: Can you try async attribute for script tags?

Comment: And your scripts must wait for loading page like this: $(function() { // here run after load page only

Comment: yep I'm going through and adding `async defer` now, which is doing the trick. But even without that, I still would have expected the scripts at the end of the code to be requested later in the process (until I read the post about preloaders).

Comment: Reasons for continuing to place scripts at the end of your HTML are if you need previous DOM/CSSOM nodes to be present or if you don't want to stop the page displaying before a script is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to place your scripts at the end of your HTML if;

1 - Your scripts need access to DOM/CSSOM nodes, therefore they have to be parsed prior to your JS.

2 - You want to display the page while the JS is still downloading and executing against the page.